# How to get OIDs from a MIB file?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib

I want to read all the objects from the MIB file that a manager has.

I developed one tool to get some data from a SNMP enabled agent. I want to enhance that tool by showing all the OIDs form the manager's MIB file.

I am using the NET-SNMP library.

I saw the following:

```
/usr/local/share/snmp/mibs/
```

folder and it contains many MIB files, but how can I form a list of the OIDs it has?

I went through the MIBs and saw the structures, but how do I get the OIDs of each and every object mentioned in the MIB files?

I want to list all the OIDs as follows:

1. `SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0  = .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0`
2. `SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 =  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0`
   ... etc

I want to scan all the MIB files and find all the OIDs from the files.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 13):

Use `snmptranslate`-command from `net-snmp` library. Try it with the following paramenters:

```
-M "directory containing your MIB file"
-m ALL
-Pu
-Tso
```

Answer (score 10):

After some problems I managed to generate the OIDs using the following command.

```
snmptranslate -Pu -Tz -M ~/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/iana:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/site:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/mibs/iana:/usr/share/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp:`pwd` -m module_name_NOT_file_name > module_name.oid
```

Comment: Thank you. Module name example for Dell iDrac from the DCMIB65 package: DELL-RAC-MIB

Answer (score 5):

To pull the `OID`s from a running `SNMP` server you might like to use the tool `snmpwalk` using the `-Ci` option . The tool comes with `Net-SNMP`.

Answer (score 1):

The other two SO QAs show how you can do it without walking a running system:

- "[net-snmp sample code to parse MIB file and extract trap related information from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330168/net-snmp-sample-code-to-parse-mib-file-and-extract-trap-related-information-from)": [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7412790/362754) shows the top-level framework of a C parser which is based on top of the Net-SNMP library.
- "[Get oid's type (syntax) from MIB using Net-SNMP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786682/get-oids-type-syntax-from-mib-using-net-snmp-api)": It is the specific function to handle an OID.

That is only the starting point. There is a lot of coding ahead from there.

Update: The another nice tool is the perl SNMP compiler packaged in SNMP::MIB::Compiler. With a script in perl you get all the MIB elements/components pulled into internal data structures and you can pick any information from there, either by looking into the structure tree or by dumping the tree and do a post-parsing on the dump.